# How do i refresh a value from a CSV once the CSV is updated on interval in R?

Tags: r, shiny

EDIT:  I've made changes based upon below feedback but i'm still having the same issue with the file not refreshing.  I've updated the code below with the edits as well as the function which made it difficult to reproduce

I have a CSV file that is being updated every 120 seconds.  I am then doing calculations against this file and changing the color of text in ui.r.

I am really struggling with the syntax and while i can get everything to work when i launch the app, make changes, and relaunch the app, I cannot get my app to auto update.

The below code works fine when executed together in the console.  So i'm confident I can read the file, do my calculation, and assign a value.

```
source("BusinessLogic.R") #This contains getColor()
my_df <- read.csv("test.csv")
my_value <- mean(my_df$score)
ui_value <- getColor(my_value)
ui_value
>[1] "yellow"
```

However in my full code, have two issues:
1) It seems as though my app is reading the file from memory instead of actually checking it again every time i launch the app

2) I cannot get the app to autorefresh the file and update the UI.

I was previously playing with IntervalLater but switching to reactiveFileReader thinking it might be easier.  I've commented out the some of the variations i've been trying.

```
library(shiny)

#source("BusinessLogic.R") #Contains function getColor() 
#my_df <- read.csv("test.csv")

ui <- htmlTemplate(
  text_ = '
  <html>
  <head> 
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <script type="application/shiny-singletons"></script>
  <script type="application/html- 
  dependencies">json2[2014.02.04];jquery[1.12.4];shiny[1.2.0]</script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <p style="color:{{ui_value}}">color</p>
  </body>
  </html>'
)
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  getColor <- function(x) {
    if (x > 80) {
      result <- "green"
    }
    else if (x > 50) {
      result <- "yellow"
    }
    else {
      result <- "red"
    }
    return(result)
  }
  my_df <- reactiveFileReader(1000, session, 'test.csv', read.csv)
  #my_df <- read.csv("test.csv")
  observe({
    invalidateLater(1000, session)
    my_value <- mean(my_df()$score)
    output$ui_value <- getColor(my_value)
  })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

When executed correctly, the UI would update this color to red green or whatever anytime the average in that particular column (score) changes.

Comment: Make sure you are using `my_df()` to call the variable since it is reactive.

Comment: Try putting `my_df <- read.csv("test.csv")` under the observer as well, this will call the read.csv function when it invalidates (re-runs) but I am not sure if it will still be stubborn. Note you will need to remove the `()` following the call since it would no longer be considered reactive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1) It seems as though my app is reading the file from memory instead
>   of actually checking it again every time i launch the app

You are not calling the file correctly once it is uploaded to the reactive varaible `my_df`

Instead:

```
my_df <- reactiveFileReader(1000, session, 'test.csv', read.csv)
    my_value <- mean(my_df()$score)
```

> 2) I cannot get the app to autorefresh the file and update the UI.

You are only running your server code once as you are not using any reactive environments to re-analyze the result.

```
observe({
 invalidateLater(1000, session)
 my_value <- mean(my_df()$score)
    output$ui_value <- getColor(my_value)
})
```

Using an observe function with `invalidateLater` allows us to re-run the reactive expression at the same rate the file should be re-uploaded.

Note: I cannot test this code as it is not reproducible.

Comment: Thanks for the right direction.  I went ahead and added how getColor works as it's a simple function.